# debootstrap local download dir

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Can someone tell me where does `debootstrap` store downloaded packages that it's about to install?

Possibly also the download method would be interesting (wget/curl/apt-get).

In my case I run:

```
sudo debootstrap --variant=build --arch=i386 precise /srv/chroot/precise_i386 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
```

All packages are correctly downloaded and installed, but didn't find them in the `/var/cache/apt/archives` where apt-get would download them normally.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it myself, to my surprise, they're under:

```
/srv/chroot/precise_i386/var/cache/apt/archives
```

So it sounds like they get downloaded to chrooted apt cache.